# how can i increase a number inside OnTriggerEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so i'm trying to increase my score every time i hit a wall (IsTrigger) but when i try to increase it, it doesn't work and still 100

so this is the code im having problem with

```
    public Text scoreText;
    public int score = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }
    // Add Some Score To The Text When The Player Hit The CheckPoint
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.name == "Player")
        {
            score += 100;
            scoreText.text = score.ToString();
            Debug.Log(score);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is clearly in `c#` ... instead you rather ant to tag your question with `unity3d` as this is the main framework / API you are asking about

Comment: And well ... you increase the value of the field `score` but it is in no way connected to the displayed text ... you have to inform the display that it shall now display a new value -> `score += 100; scoreText.text = score.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

When doing the trigger/collision test, make sure you add one
`Debug.Log()` outside of the condition check. In your case,

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.name == "Player")
    {
        score += 100;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        Debug.Log(score);
    }
    Debug.Log("Just want make sure it indeed triggered.");
}
```

In most case, other than the issue with the code, it is highly possible the **Rigidbody** component is not added to the GO.

Another part which I am not sure since I am not using Unity for quite a long time now. You can move the UI text update code outside of the trigger if you want.

Comment: I think the main issue is already answered due to OP not updating the displayed text after increasing only the field value ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the text after changing the value, in your case you have to update "scoreText" according to the new "score" value. The simple way to do it is like that:

```cs
    public Text scoreText;
    public int score = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }
    // Add Some Score To The Text When The Player Hit The CheckPoint
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.name == "Player")
        {
            score += 100;
            scoreText.text = score.ToString();
            Debug.Log(score);
        }
    }
```

It is better to have a method called "ChangeScore" which includes updating the "score" value and updating the "scoreText" at the same time. It is better to do so since you might forget to update the text in other cases if you have to change the score somewhere else.
Example:

```cs
    [Tooltip("The player's initial score.")]
    [SerializeField] private int initScore = 0;
    
    // Serialized since you have to set the reference for it.
    [SerializeField] private Text scoreText;

    private int score = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        ChangeScore(initScore);
    }

    // Method used to change the current player's score and update the text.
    void ChangeScore(int changeValue)
    {
        this.score += changeValue;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }
    
    // Add Some Score To The Text When The Player Hit The CheckPoint
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            ChangeScore(100);
            Debug.Log(score);
        }
    }
```

Another side note: I wouldn't use tags or names while checking colliding, its better to check if the colliding object got the PlayerController script

```
if(collider.GetComponent<PlayerController>())
```

instead of

```
if (collider.gameObject.name == "Player")
```

Comment: actually i did this but forgot to write it on the post but it adds 100100100 instead of 300

Comment: The only way it would show 100100100 instead of 300 if you add the 100 to a string variable instead of int variable. So to avoid that you have to add 100 to the int variable "score" then set the new text with "score" value. Set it, not add it. Don't use += to the string use "=". Let me know if you still face any issues regarding it,

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it i put the code on the **Player** script not on the **CheckPoint** script

```
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.tag == "ScoreCheckPoint")
        {
            score += 100;
            scoreText.text = score.ToString();
            Debug.Log(score);
        }
    }
```